# Adwords API not returning Final URLs for ExpandedTextAds

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get the final url array from a Google Adwords Java API ExpandedTextAdd. I can get all of the other fields, such as the headlines, description and path urls, but calling getfinalUrls always returns null, even though the ad being requested has a final url.

This is my selector:

```
selector.fields(AdGroupAdField.Id, AdGroupAdField.AdGroupId, AdGroupAdField.Status, AdGroupAdField.Labels)
                .orderAscBy(AdGroupAdField.Id)
                .equals(AdGroupAdField.AdGroupId, adGroupIds.toString())
                .in(AdGroupAdField.Status, "ENABLED", "PAUSED")
                .equals("AdType", getAdType());
```

There doesn't seem to be a AdGroupAdField for final urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from the AdWords API team, and someone on my team noticed your question. To select final URLs using **AdGroupAdField**, check out the field **CreativeFinalUrls**. The fields **CreativeFinalMobileUrls** and **CreativeFinalAppUrls** are also available. You can find out more details about these fields in the [Ad API documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201609/AdGroupAdService.Ad#finalurls). If you have any further questions for the AdWords API team, please post on our [AdWords API forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api).

Best,

Nadine, AdWords API Team